# How to rtrim the slash character (/)?

Tags: t-sql, azure-synapse-analytics, trim

```
rtrim('txt/','/')
```

What if we cannot use this version of the rtrim function.. How else to remove the trailing '/' from the end of a string (if present)?

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
(
  str VARCHAR (63)
);
```

Populate it:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('testing/'), ('testing');
```

And run the following SQL:

```
SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN LEFT(REVERSE(str), 1) != '/' THEN str
    ELSE LEFT(str, (LEN(str) - 1))
  END AS str
FROM test;
```

Result:

```
str
testing
testing
```

Fiddle available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/ozFWJUzP).

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways of achieving the desired result.

Another option is using [STUFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN right(str,1) <> '/' THEN str
    ELSE STUFF(str,DATALENGTH(str), 1, '')
  END AS str
FROM test;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/gxVe5V6x

If you want to update the table and remove the last `/` from the string

```
update  test
set str = STUFF(str,DATALENGTH(str), 1, '') 
where right(str,1)='/'  ;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/3ztPciO_